# How to search for raw URL

Tags: support, search, hyperlinks

How do you search for a "real" URL when it is obfuscated with markdown?  For example, if someone has this in a post: `[bar](http://foo.com)`, searching for `url: *foo*` will return nothing.

I guess this could be handled more generally if there was a search option to search the raw text in a post without markdown formatting.  But I couldn't find anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search for `url:foo` (which is equivalent to `url:*foo*`) - no space between the `url:` and the URL search term.

The [search `url:foo`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Afoo) returns results where *any* URL contains `foo`. Here's the search display in the right toolbar when performing the search:

[image]

Compare that to the search display related to the [search `url: *foo*`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3A+*foo*):

[image]

The former has a specific query (or search option) in place, while the latter is just a generic search query.